# ComponentQuery.query doesn't pull up all results that it should

Tags: extjs

I am having having little success with issuing `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` statements to retrieve components from the document.

**[Example Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5jo)**

The following work:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel')
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel[title=Layout]')
```

The following don't work:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#imageHolder'); //itemId
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel#imageHolder'); //itemId of a panel
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('image'); //xtype
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('contactcarousel'); //user defined xtype
```

Can anybody kindly help me understand why those don't work? I am following the [Extjs Ext.ComponentQuery Doc Page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).

Comment: I am fairly sure this is happening because the debug console in the sencha fiddle environment is actually set to the sencha fiddle ui and not the the fiddle itself.  I was executing those snippets in the console in order to learn extjs (since I am very new at this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In console, change `<top frame>` to `uxiframe-xxxx` and it will work. Other frame is as other browser window, you must switch to it to access the page.

Comment: Thank you - you are absolutely right.  I didn't realize you could do change the targeted frame like that.